# Routing Issues on Exchange 2010 and 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2003, migration, exchange-migration

I am working on the migration of exchange 2003 to exchange 2010, so far the 2010 is up and running, I move a test mailbox to 2010, and internal email works from 2010 to 2003, no problem, i can send emails from 2010 to the outside, my problem is receiving emails from the outside to the user on the 2010 box, we have a 3rd party service for spam filter, all inbound and outbound is managed and controlled by the service, I dont know what I am missing, why I cant get external emails to the users on the 2010 box....

Any ideas? I have been playing the the receive connectors, but still can figure this one out!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too open to answer, there could be lots of reasons why you're not getting e-mails.

A good place to start your troubleshooting is by using the **Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer**: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

Hope this helps.

Comment: server is no FE the internet, all email needs to flow thru our exchange 2003, outbound works just fine, but the incoming is not being delivered to the 2010 box, working with the MX, PTR, and all DNS related will be after getting the 2010 fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea to throw out-- have you made sure you've got a public ptr record out there pointing to your 2010 server?

Comment: How is that related to the problem?

Comment: I've had the same issue when setting up a new relay server.  Outside mail wasn't coming in, calling our isp and asking them to update our ptr record fixed the issue.  Reverse dns lookups were failing on the outside before the ptr got updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I had an smart host on the exchange 2003, this config is not supported with the RGC on 2010., removed from 2003 and everything works!!!

Hope this help some else to resolve their issue.